# Seleccionar como pre requisito .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8 en VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, windows-server-2012, windows-installer

He actualizado mi proyecto a .NET 4.8 (Actualmente es la versión recomendada por Microsoft.)
Pero no aparece en el cuadro de diálogo para poder seleccionarla como requisito en el proyecto instalador:

[image: Requisitos previos]

Las búsquedas en Google no han dado demasiada luz, hay soluciones para otras versiones de vs como por ejemplo [esta](https://superuser.com/questions/1427728/visual-studio-2019-publish-prerequisites-dialog-is-missing-net-framework-4-8). Y las que he encontrado para vs2017 tratan sobre otra versión del .NET Framework, como por ejemplo [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079493/missing-net-framework-4-0-in-visual-studio-2017-prerequisites-when-publishing). Ninguna de las dos funciona en mi caso.

La plataforma en la que debo instalarlo es Windows Server 2012, la versión por defecto del Windows installer que trae es la 5.0, y he encontrado que no existe paquete redistribuible de esta versión.

Tampoco he encontrado el Windows installer para añadirlo como pre requisito ¿No será necesario con VS2017?

Comment: Tengo entendido que sólo funcionará con VS2019. En el segundo ejemplo que diste para vs2017 dan una respuesta similar, por lo mismo tampoco aparece como target el Framework 4.0 y para ello, debes usar vs2015. Me parece que el problema está en la versión del VS. Microsoft ha trabajado duro en desatender el resto de las versiones de VS.

Comment: Solo 2019 en Adelante, en este momento ya estamos en VS 2022